# Принцип единой ответственности

Tags: java, ооп, solid

Написал код деления в столбик двух чисел и вывод графического результата в консоль. Есть два основных метода `divide(divedend, divider)` и `display(number1, number2, lineCount)` - вывод результата построчный. Метод divide() построчно выполняет поэтапное деление и в конце вычислений значений на конкретной строке вызывает метод `display()`.

Ментор говорит, что у меня нарушен  Принцип единой ответственности. Что может быть не так? Если можно с краткими примерами!

```
public void divide(int dividend, int divider) {

    int lineCount = 1;
    int result = 0;
    int dividendRemainder = 0;
    int elementCount = 0;
    int dividendPart = 0;
    int subtractedDigit = 0;

    display(dividend, divider, lineCount);
    lineCount++;

    String dividendLine = String.valueOf(dividend);
    String[] dividendDigits = dividendLine.split("");

    while (elementCount < dividendDigits.length) {

        if (elementCount == 0) {
            dividendPart = Integer.parseInt(dividendDigits[elementCount]);
        } else {
            dividendPart = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dividendPart) + dividendDigits[elementCount]);
        }

        if (dividendPart >= divider) {
            result = dividendPart / divider;
            dividendRemainder = dividendPart % divider;
            subtractedDigit = result * divider;

            if (lineCount == 2) {
                display(dividend, divider, lineCount);

            } else {
                display(dividendPart, subtractedDigit, lineCount);
            }

            dividendPart = dividendRemainder;
            lineCount++;
            elementCount++;

        } else {
            elementCount++;
        }
    }

    lineCount = 0;
    display(dividend, dividendRemainder, lineCount);    
}
public void display() {}
```

Comment: Ваш класс имеет две обязанности -- делит два числа и выводит результаты. В этом и нарушение SRP.

Comment: получается надо разбить на два класса?

Comment: Да (смотрите ответ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Принцип единственной обязанности (*Single Responsibility Principle*) формулируется следующим образом:

**У класса должна быть только одна причина для изменения.**

Если класс берет на себя несколько обязанностей, то у него появляется несколько причин для изменения, следовательно, нарушается SRP.

В Вашем примере у класса две обязанности -- выполнение математических операций и вывод на экран.

Что делать? -- Вынести обязанности в разные классы.

*Под одной обязанностью не обязательно понимается один метод. У класса может быть несколько методов, но обязанность при этом может быть одна.*

Comment: *У класса несколько обязанностей >> много причин для изменения >> нарушен SRP*. Среднее звено в таком "доказательстве" явно лишнее. *"У класса должна быть только одна причина для изменения"* - это трактовка Мартина, и скорее является 99% индикатором соблюдения SRP, а не его описанием. ИМХО.